# In google cloud platform, can we name the instances in a specific series in instance group?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I'm new to the google cloud platform, I've created an instance group. I want to know that, Is it possible to name the instances of instance group in a specific series?

For eg. :

> my-GCP-instance-001,
> my-GCP-instance-002,
> my-GCP-instance-003

then if a new instance is created it should acquire the name

> my-GCP-instance-004

let's say instance group scales in (kills an instance), let's assume it **terminates**

> my-GCP-instance-002

when it scales out and creates a new instance it should identify the **missing series**

> my-GCP-instance-002

and name its instance

> my-GCP-instance-002.

Let me know if it is possible, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

When creating an instance group, you can supply the `--base-instance-name` flag. Each VM in that instance group will be assigned a random string as part of its name. The base name is prepended to this random string. For example, if you set the base name to my-GCP-instance-, VMs will have names like my-GCP-instance-yahs and my-GCP-instance-qtyz.

You can also take a look at [Working with managed instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/working-with-managed-instances#adding_instances_with_specific_names):

> If you have a system that depends on specific names, use the [gcloud tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/create-instance) or API to add VMs with specific names to an existing MIG.
> The names that you assign to these managed instances persist if the MIG recreates the VM. For more information about preserving the state of MIG instances, see [stateful MIGs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/stateful-migs).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response but I'm not looking for prefixes to the random string, I'm looking for suffix which should not random i.e there should be a pattern like 001, 002...

Example:

If the instance group is "my-GCP-group", the instance creation should start with my-GCP-group-001, the second instance should be my-GCP-group-002, my-GCP-group-003, and so on. let's say my-GCP-group-002 is terminated, when the instance group scales out it should create the instance which is missing in the series pattern i.e the new instance created should have a name equals to  "my-GCP-group-002".